# Elegant way of printing last n-2 lines in a file

Tags: bash

I want to print the last n-2 lines of a file where n is the number of lines in the file.
this can be done by doing n = `wc -l` -2 and then `tail -n $file`.

But is there any better way to do this ?? I require this function in bash too often ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `tail -n +3 file` to skip first two lines (and output the rest n-2 lines).

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, `tail -n +3 file` should do what you want.

From `man tail`

```
       -n, --lines=K
          output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth
```